# Fantasy fiction book about a man in search of crystals or gems that gave power

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book a while back maybe 5 years ago. It was about a man that was hunting/killing creatures (in a canyon I think) to get a crystal/gem from them that gave power or magic. I only read the first book as the second wasn't out yet.

Comment: I have marked this question as a Duplicate. This does not mean that it was a bad question, but simply that it's considered to have been asked, and answered, before (story-id questions are special in that all of them targeting the same work are considered duplicates). You will still get points for upvotes, and can receive comments, but answers will be closed. You can still formally accept the current answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. You will get points for doing so.

Answer (score 5):

The description is very vague, but this could perhaps be [*The Way of Kings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Way_of_Kings), the first book in Brandon Sanderson's ongoing Stormlight Archive series.

One plot thread in that book involves Kaladin, a slave who is forced to participate in a series of hunts for Chasmfiends, huge insect-like creatures which contain a single Gemheart.

Comment: Ahhhh man...that's the one!  Thanks...it was starting to drive me insane!

Comment: @Ash: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].